# Cannot get property 'mavenRepo' on extra properties extension as it does not exist in react native jitsi meet

Tags: react-native

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '/Users/user/jitsi-meet-master/android/build.gradle' line: 60
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'jitsi-meet'.

  > Cannot get property 'mavenRepo' on extra properties extension as it does not exist
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
ERROR: Cannot get property 'mavenRepo' on extra properties extension as it does not exist